# How can I activate a vtt file on my Azure Media Player (AMP) via js?

Tags: javascript, azure-media-services

I instantiate my AMPs via js. I now have urls for .vtt files for each video, but I'm unclear how to associate each vtt with each AMP. The AMP docs note objects "Cea708CaptionSettings" and "Imsc1CaptionSettings" however I don't see a url or src property for these. Any clues greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure Media Player make sure you're adding the link to the VTT separately. See the [example](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/videotag_webvtt.html) on the AMP sample.